# I have text from textview, I want to erase/delete some data before an empty line

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a text from a textview, I want to delete text before the empty line.

For example:

abcdefgehijklmnopq
abcdefgehijklmnopq

zxcvbvbv
ahtahhd
Here i is
some of them

I want to delete the upper portion of the string, first two lines. these 2 lines may be 3, may be 4 and so on. The logic is to delete the text before an empty line. Because I want to delete the header and need the lower portion text come from different text fields.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari sir i have seperate the upper portion using str.split("\\n\n") but i need to delete it.

Comment: apply str.replace("\n","");

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
String lines[] = s.split("\\r?\\n");
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(s.split("\\r?\\n"));
System.out.println("string is " + list.get(list.size()-1));
```